# AngularJS Get Attribute Value

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have the following angular object in my controller

```
$scope.students = [{:id => 1, :state => 'active'}, {:id => 2, :state => 'suspended'}]
```

How can i get id of all students whose state is active? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways but the easiest I can think of is adding an activeStudent function in your scope, something like this:

```
$scope.activeStudent = function(){
  return _.filter($scope.students, function(s){
    return s.state == "active";
  });
}
```

and in your views you would use activeStudent() in your binding.

Comment: Thanks Very much Schmurfy! Is there a better way to get the ids of all  the students instead of looping and collecting id? like **$scope.students.collect(&:id)** Thanks again!

Comment: I use underscore with angularjs and I am pretty happy with it (I used it in the example), you can look at http://underscorejs.org/#map and http://underscorejs.org/#pluck .